# What does "times" mean in the newspaper "Washington Times"?

Tags: word-meaning

What does “times” mean in the newspaper “Washington Times”?

I have always wanted to ask about this, but feared it might be so obvious that I would look like a fool. For that many *times*, I haven't before experienced that level of hesitation with any other question, but I think now is the right *time* to ask, anyway.

Comment: For the record, I think this is a perfectly reasonable learner's question. No need to feel foolish for asking.

Answer (score 2):

In UK we have "The Times", "The Financial Times", "The Observer", "The Guardian" and "The Daily Mail" and so on.

These titles are supposed to reflect the idea that the newspaper is up-to-the-minute in its reporting.

I looked for **times** in Oxford and Cambridge Dictionaries but neither seems to have this usage from the Bob Dylan song

> [The times they are a changin'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times_They_Are_a-Changin%27).

Comment: Macmillan, under its definition for _times_, has: _the circumstances and ideas of the present age_

Comment: It's not unlike the word "news" itself, which tells us that the information is "new" rather than historical.