# Meaning of "Times" in "NY Times"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know times can be used in "old times" or "in times of war" for instance, in the general meaning of an epoch.

I'm wondering what is the meaning of "times" in "[NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/)", is that just "our epoch in NY", something like news from NY?

Comment: Duplicate of [What does "times" mean in the newspaper "Washington Times"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183008/what-does-times-mean-in-the-newspaper-washington-times)

Comment: Yes, the times in New York City. Times: these are difficult times [period in history].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Times* as a newspaper title started with the English paper *The Times*, which started life as *The Daily Universal Register* but the editor was unhappy with the name being abbreviated. Other papers then basically copied it.

I'm not sure that there's any authoritative record of how he meant the title to be read. It's a name, after all. However, I suspect it was meant to evoke expressions such as "*sign of the **times***", "*life and **times***", and so on. This might be taken to be mostly referring to "current times", alluding to what we now call "current affairs".

Comment: Interesting alternative to [the other](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183008).